# calculating the expiry date from a given period of time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a system am working on, its a rental system. basically the administrator is supposed to record tenants and i want that when a tenant pays for 3 months, the system should automatically check the current date and automatically generates the end date without the user actually checking the calendar to find out when the tenant's rental period is supposed to expire and thereafter save that date in the sql db..plus when the end date is approaching or has passed it should alert the user.

Comment: This is not free coding site. Try to solve your problem yourself first. Then you can ask our help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Assiuming you have a DB called 'tenents' in this format

[image]

Now you can use a query like this to generate the end date.

```
SELECT tenentID,DATE_ADD(Join_Date,INTERVAL 90 DAY) AS yourPayDate FROM tenents
```

Comment: i figured out what i wanted.....but thanks its from this link http://benholland.me/tutorials/2012/03/11/adding-and-subtracting-dates-and-times-in-php.html